# Disabling CPU Turbo Boost causes unexpected increase in GPU power usage?

Tags: cpu, gpu, power, nvidia-graphics-card, turbo-boost

When I disable the CPU Turbo Boost the following happens:

- the CPU clock and power correctly **decrease**
- the GPU power consumption and temperature **increase** - despite 0% GPU load and no change in GPU clocks.

Any idea why?

Look at the graph below, paying attention to the Turbo Boost Off and On events (red and blue vertical lines)
[image: CPU/GPU chart]

Whenever I toggle the Turbo Boost, the power consumption on the CPU/GPU swaps...

[image: CPU/GPU Power]

... yet there is no increase in either GPU Load or GPU Clock. (GPU Load is the dark green line)

[image: LPU/GPU Load]

My machine is idle, no heavy GPU or CPU processes.

I'm puzzled and couldn't find any documentation suggesting that this should happen. Why would lowering the CPU clock cause the GPU power consumption to increase? I could understand it if GPU was to 'take over' some of the CPU's load, but GPU load doesn't move a muscle. If you could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

**CPU**: Intel i7-8750H | **GPU**: NVidia RTX 2070 Max-Q | Mounted on Gigabyte 15-X9 laptop | Running on Windows 10 Pro, NVidia Driver 445.87

Comment: 0% GPU load? Not very likely. Are you sure all these graphs are referring to the same GPU? Because it doesn’t look like they are. 0°C doesn’t look right either except when the GPU is maybe fully disabled.

Comment: Double checked - they all refer to the same GPU. Why do you say that it be unreasonable hot have 0% GPU load or 0*C temp? Do you have somewhere I could read more about these claims? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add comments yet (due low reputation points) so adding a suggestion here: in Nvidia Control Panel > 3D Settings > Set PhysX Configuration > Select a PhysX processor: you should have 3 options:

- Auto
- (Your Nvidia)
- CPU

What is you current selection? Do you still see GPU increase when PhysX=CPU?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, although changing it from Auto (which it was set to originally) to CPU didn't seem to change anything. Any other clues?

Comment: Sorry no other clues. maybe try to update the drivers of both your video card (if there is any new one) but also your Motherboard (specially related to Intel CPU/chipset).

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because of lack of power(tdp), there is not enough power to prvide both gpu and cpu in max turbo moost, so when the cpu power go down, there is enough power for gpu ,so gpu power go up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).